# Http Authentication in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to implement http authentication in iPhone using objective C.
Can anyone give me some idea or any dummy project that is implementing the http authentication.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpBasicAuthentication in IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761445/httpbasicauthentication-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

The excellent **[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)** library handles Basic, Digest and NTLM authentication with ease. I recommend it unless you really want to write it yourself.

Comment: Hi,Thnx dude...I went through that library but didn't get the stuffs. can I see those files I'm not able to download those files or else can u give some sample code in which you are using http authentication for validating the user id and password. And can you please clear me about these things.

Comment: Hi,Thnx dude...I went through that library but didn't get the stuffs. can I see those files I'm not able to download those files or else can u give some sample code in which you are using http authentication for validating the user id and password.Actually I'm using CFNetwork components.can you please clear me about these things based on those components, 1. can I use those components for https://encrypted.google.com or any other site, 2. how would I know dat the servr is returning challenge for that url, 3. how to use credentials for that url, 4. what type of credential can I use, Thanx a lot

Comment: @Kamal I have no advice on doing it yourself: I've only used the ASIHTTPRequest library itself because it works so well, I'm not tried to pull pieces of code out of the library with my own CFNetwork code.